# GPUImage filter chain

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am trying to apply to filters to an image using GPUImage but i am only getting the last filter applied to the image.

Here is the code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];

    //Set Brightness to 60
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [GPUImageBrightnessFilter new];
    [brightnessFilter setBrightness:2];

    //Set Contrast to 12
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [GPUImageContrastFilter new];
    [contrastFilter setContrast:1.0];

    [contrastFilter addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [stillImageSource addTarget:contrastFilter];

    [contrastFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [stillImageSource processImage];

    UIImage *outputImage1 = [contrastFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    imageView.image = outputImage1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)doctorTheImage:(UIImage *)originalImage
{

   const float brownsMask[6] = {85, 255, 85, 255, 85, 255};


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 1.0,1.0, 1.0, 1);


    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height));

    CGImageRef brownRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(imageView.image.CGImage, brownsMask);

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, imageView.image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    //CGImageRef whiteRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(brownRef, whiteMask);
    CGContextDrawImage (context, imageRect, brownRef);

    //[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height)];

    CGImageRelease(brownRef);
   // CGImageRelease(whiteRef);

    UIImage *doctoredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return doctoredImage;
}
```

you can try this code to change the specific range of colors defined in mask. if u 
want more referance u can refer these stack overflow link : [How to change the skin color of face from the source image in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236934/how-to-change-the-skin-color-of-face-from-the-source-image-in-ios)