# Change Face Color From main color in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimage

I work on application in ios and i need tool or code which change only face color of image .

I already get face in uiimage.

Now How apply RGB color Change to Uiimage of that face?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: are you wan to change face color in terms of improve screen color?

Comment: This is a very complex problem, and there is no "just xyz" answer. The cleanest answer is probably to use the Color Cube Core Image filter, and create a color cube that maps the ranges of colors found in the face to a new color range, but that's non-trivial to work out.

Comment: @NimitParekh yes change skin color like white face to some dark or some dark face person s face color change to white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Synch"];  // your face image here
imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

// imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // set different tint color here and image will get that color

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Image should be `png` file. Synch image is in png format in example.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I Try This but it s not work me i update scrrenshot after use your code.it not show face and make it full red

Answer (score 0):

One of the library can achieve you goal and that is change the skin color of the image.

[YUCIHighPassSkinSmoothing](https://github.com/YuAo/YUCIHighPassSkinSmoothing)

Sample Here.

[image]